Is it possible to efficiently create a matrix M in which the elements are the sum of all possible "path-products" of matrix A?
I have a lower triangular matrix A where $a_{ij}=0, j\geq i$. I want to build a lower triangular matrix M where $m_{ij}$ is the sum of all the possible "path-products" from index $i$ to index $j$ of matrix A. For example,
$$ m_{21} = a_{21}$$ $$ m_{31} = a_{31} + a_{32}a_{21} $$ $$ m_{41} = a_{41}  + a_{42}a_{21} + a_{43}a_{31} + a_{43}a_{32}a_{21}$$ $$...$$
Is there any closed-form representation of matrix M using A, or is it possible to generate M in an (efficient, scalable) iterative way?

If I've understood you correctly, we have
$$M = A + A^2 + A^3 + \dots = \frac{A}{I - A}.$$
(In general the notation $\frac{X}{Y}$ for two matrices is ambiguous since it could refer either to $XY^{-1}$ or $Y^{-1} X$, but in this case the numerator and denominator commute so it's unambiguous.)

Though it would be required that $|A|<1$, right? But it seems like (if we assume $A$ is $n \times n$ dimensional) $M = \sum_{k=1}^n {A^k} = (A - A^{n+1})(I-A)^{-1}$

@H-a-y-K: that's unnecessary. $A$ is nilpotent so this sum is actually finite.

Wow, very cool!
